# Latest User Messages section does not display "Something else..."-type mod messages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderator-tools

There's a bug in the "Latest User Messages" section of the mod users page [`/admin/users`](//stackoverflow.com/admin/users):

Custom "Something else... (with edits)"-type messages does not show up in this list.

A screenshot is not necessary as it is regarding a particular type of message missing from the list, but this should be easily reproducible.

This issue affects [Personal Mod Message History](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#personal-mod-message-history-) userscript, as it uses that list to display messages sent by us.

---

If possible, I would like to request a **separate similar list that only contains messages sent by the current mod** so that we can review our own message history separately. Currently it's not easy tracking older sent messages as all the incoming/outgoing messages between all mods and users are mixed into the same list.

Comment: Ping me about this privately with an example, please; can't reproduce.